# Scheduled Crontab is not working to execute the Python Program

Tags: python, cron

I have scheduled a python program to run on daily basis at 12:30 pm using the below cron tab option...But it is not working anymore...Can someone please help me to modify the scheduled crontab to run the program as per the schedule.

30 12 * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python  /Users/.../desktop/Python/ParamikoSShAcceSS.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the crontab to dump the output of your script execution to a log file so you can capture and review any errors that arise during cron execution.

```
30 12 * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/.../desktop/Python/ParamikoSShAcceSS.py >> /tmp/paramkiosshoutput.log 2>&1
```

Review the `/tmp/paramkiosshoutput.log` after the next scheduled execution and see what output is there.

Also double check the permissions of `/Users/.../desktop/Python/ParamikoSShAcceSS.py`.  Ensure that it has execute permissions.  If not, add them:

```
chmod a+x /Users/.../desktop/Python/ParamikoSShAcceSS.py
```

Comment: .. sry for the delayed response... i have executed the script as per your advice... no details are getting stored in /tmp/paramkiosshoutput.log 2>&1 and permission also changed.but still the script is not working as per scheduled Crontab

Comment: The file path would be /tmp/paramkiosshoutput.log.  The "2>&1" is just a redirection command you add to the end of your command line or crontab to merge standard error and standard output streams into one so that they both can be written to /tmp/paramkiosshoutput.log.  What user are you setting the crontab for?  Is it the root user?  If so, log in as root and execute the "mail" command to check root's mail messages.  If there are previous crontab failures where you didn't redirect the output to a log file, they'll likely show up in root's mailbox.  Check those mail messages for errors.